# Does having multiple dots in a filename bad?

Tags: php, naming-conventions, filenames

Is there any organization or articles that says we can or should not have multiple dots in filename? I'm really confuse if I should use dot in PHP files, I might break some rules or standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filename with multiple dots does not break any PHP naming conventions, because file names are not PHP variable names; they belong to the OS really and PHP only sees them as strings.

**EDIT**

I looked around and found cases for multiple dots: version numbers and dates.  There has been some discussion as to whether these increase or decrease SEO value but I have not found anything conclusive.  It does show however that they are used.

Tip: Try the following Google search: *seo periods in filenames*

Comment: Yeah, I know in PHP it doesn't matter, I just mentioned that so people won't consider my question as NOT APPROPRIATE FOR THE SITE or something. Do you know any articles that will prove that it's okay? To OS's, HTTP Servers etc?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.  PHP does give the usual access to basename, dirname, and pathinfo, and yes as you know they are agnostic to the number of dots and will indeed work fine if there are multiple dots.  As far as conventions go, in my experience it is rare to have multiple dots; they tend to show up in names like `people.txt.bak` and they do look a little unusual.  However a quick search of "File naming conventions" did not turn up anything that codifies a purposeful avoidance.  If someone else comes up with a good answer either way I will withdraw mine.