# double dot in html name file

Tags: php

I'm curious about this naming file with double dots just like this: "file.name.php".

Will this be still a valid url even if it is working inside my page where PHP include call this filename like this setup:

```
<?php include ('includes/pages/file.name.php'); ?>
```

Am I going to have problem / conflict if i implement this to my site over to server & browsers?

Comment: You can have dots in the filename. `a...a` is a valid filename (at least on Linux).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does having multiple dots in a filename bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290989/does-having-multiple-dots-in-a-filename-bad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have dots `.` in the file name. It's still a valid file.

If you are looking for good practice then use hyphen `-` or underscore `_`

**Example,**

`file-name.php` or `file_name.php`

Answer (score 1):

Multiple dots in a file name is not a problem.

This is a repeat question:
[Does having multiple dots in a filename bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290989/does-having-multiple-dots-in-a-filename-bad)